# Effect of nucleus geometry and states on the Coulomb barrier and the electric potential well surrounding the nucleus

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

In some models of the nucleus it has a geometric aspect due to the combination and alignments of the charges, magnetic moments and spins of the protons and neutrons it contains. Even in models that look at the nucleus as a more Quantum mechanical soup result in certain nuclei having an overall spin and magnetic moment and shape.

Would any of these effects have an impact on the surrounding electric field? Normally we consider the Coulomb Barrier and electric potential well to be spherically symmetric. Is this the case, however, for atoms with nuclei that have structure or overall spin or magnetic moment along a certain axis. Or would the potential be modified symmetrically around that axis.

Comment: Could you maybe clarify your question? Do you want to know what effect the shape, spin, and magnetic moment have on the electric field? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by the "electric potential well", since there is only positive charge in the nucleus.